# jQuery function when elements are within 400 pixels of the top of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following but I'm getting stuck.  Any tips would be appreciated

- get all the data-position values from the divs (.examples)
- when one of those is 400 pixels from the top do magic, do magic each time one of them is 400 pixels from the top

In my current  set up it says that "contentPosition.offset" is not a function

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
            var contentPosition = [];
            $('.examples').each(function () { //Get elements that have an id=
                contentPosition.push($(this).data('position')); //add id to array
            });

            var top = contentPosition.offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
            if (top > 400) {
                console.log('COMBO BREAKER');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nesting is out and also you need to use $(this) instead of the contentposition array as the object to test.  (I'm assuming here that you want the COMBO BREAKER to appear when the object is 400 or less pixels from the top).

See this working fiddle (updated):
https://jsfiddle.net/sijpkes/brjpt501/4/

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
        var contentPosition = [];
        $('.examples').each(function () { //Get elements that have an id=
            contentPosition.push($(this).data('position')); //add id to array

              var top = $(this).offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();

              if (top < 400) {
                   console.log('COMBO BREAKER');
              }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `contentPosition` is an array of elements. You may need to use:

```
contentPosition[i].offset().top
```

Where, `i` is an iterator for the loop.

So, if you wanna do something on each of them, you need to:

```
for (i = 0; i < contentPosition.length; i++) {
    var top = contentPosition[i].offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
    if (top > 400) {
        console.log('COMBO BREAKER');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

contentPosition is an array right? So how about looping through it and checking that position:

```
for(var i = 0; i < contentPosition.length; i++){
  var top = contentPosition[i].offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
  if (top > 400) {
    console.log('COMBO BREAKER');
  }
}
```